# Why a File returned by ContextWrapper.getDir() always exists?

Tags: android

I am making an application in which I have to save video files internally(in app memory when app is uninstalled all the filed should also be uninstalled).For this I have read many articles and googled a lot and found different solutions and after that I made a method there I wrote the code for that here is the code

```
public static boolean checkIfAlreadyDownloaded(Context context, String rhymeName) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    File rhymeDirectory = cw.getDir(Constants.INTERNAL_DIRECTORY_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (rhymeDirectory.exists()) {
        File individualRhyme = new File(rhymeDirectory, rhymeName);
        if (individualRhyme.exists())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here Constants.INTERNAL_DIRECTORY NAME is "Rhymes"
what I understand is if there is no directory then it returns false but When I install my app first time it return true.Even I uninstalled it and then reinstall it is always returning true .My question is "why it is always returning true"? Shouldn't it return false first time?Correct me please if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContextWrapper.getDir()` creates the directory if necessary, as said in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> `public File getDir (String name, int mode)`
>
> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files.

Comment: What if that directory already exists?Will it create new one or will replace it?(May be it is a silly question but I have no idea about this).

Comment: The documentation makes this quite clear if you read it: if the directory does not exist, it is created. If it does exist, the existing directory is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
  File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //Creating an   internal dir;
  File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile");
  //Getting a file within the dir.
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
  //Use the stream as usual to write into the file
```

For deleting a file from internal :

```
  if (new File("path/to/file").delete()) {
   // Deleted
    } else {
    // Not deleted
    }
```